# can't resolve fs - angular universal project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack

I have `can't resolve fs` problem, and until now I approximately have looked up all issues related to the problem in [Github](https://github.com), but can't fix it.

my problem is exactly: 
I'm working on an angular-universal project.
after I added `dom-storage` to my project, I got the `can't resolve fs` error in (browser) build process, and the main provied  solution is adding `fs: 'empty'` to `webpack.config.js`. but I tried all solutions and couldn't fix it.

after a lot, now I think the problem can be from here :
I bring up my thought. It would be appreciated if help me to know the solution.
at first, we know `angular-cli` uses webpack to does `build` angular projects (according to the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#build-target)).
and I think there is no any config file for webpack in this process, and `webpack.config.js` is only used for bundling `server.ts` file in our project. so every change in `webpack.config.js` file don't impresses on build process in

my project. now my questions are: 
 1. Am I right ?
 2. If I right, is there any way to define config file for webpack (angular-cli uses) to set everything you said in that config file ?

Comment: Same problem to me, also with Can't resolve 'os' in fast-csv extended.js

Comment: The problem appeared to me when I have installed ExcelJS (no idea if it is your problem)
Anyway for me the problem solution was map ExceJS component via script in the angular.json file in ColmpilerOptions.

            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js"
            ]

[link] (https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/810)